# How to correct my null exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a contact form using c# and web services. I would like to get an alert message if the user hasn't filled his name or when his name is a number. This is my C# code:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validation.WebService validate = new Validation.WebService();
        bool ismail = validate.isEmail(TextBox2.Text);
        if (!ismail)
          { Label1.Text = "your mail is wrong!!"; }

        Validation.nameVal valid = new Validation.nameVal();
        bool isname = valid.isName(TextBox1.Text);
        if (!isname )
        { Label2.Text = "Your name is wrong!!"; }

        else if (isname==null)
        { Label2.Text = "Please fill in your name"; }

        if (isname && ismail)
        {  
            { Label1.Text = null; Label2.Text = null;
            Label3.Text = "Your message has been send!";}
            }
        }
}
```

With this code, I have a null exception.

Comment: Where do you get the null pointer exception?

Comment: Where do you have a null pointer exception?

Comment: here :    bool isname = valid.isName(TextBox1.Text);

Comment: @kostas: Sounds like either `valid` is null or `TextBox1` is null on that line.  Which is it?

Comment: Why does this code compile, you have `else if (isname==null)` where `isname` is a boolean variable?

Answer (score 2):

From your comment that the exception is on the line:

```
bool isname = valid.isName(TextBox1.Text);
```

then either `valid` or `TextBox1` is null. Given that the line before is:

```
Validation.nameVal valid = new Validation.nameVal();
```

this points to it being the latter.

You need to check that `TextBox1` isn't null before de-referencing it or make sure that it is initialised correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the last bit of the code where you set `Label1.Text` and `Label2.Text` to null to:

```
Label1.Text = String.Empty; Label2.Text = String.Empty;
```

Comment: Are you setting Textbox1.Text or Textbox2.Text to null anywhere?

Comment: That would cause it. Set `textBox1.Text` to `String.Empty` instead if you want to clear its contents.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that perhaps the validate is failing, or, possibly the setting of the label text to null is causing the issues. The code below should help

```
  Validation.WebService validate = new Validation.WebService();
    bool ismail = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox2.Text)) &&  validate.isEmail(TextBox2.Text);
    if (!ismail) 
    {
        Label1.Text = "your mail is wrong!!";
    }
    Validation.nameVal valid = new Validation.nameVal();

    bool isname = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text)) && valid.isName(TextBox1.Text); 

    if (!isname) 
    {
        Label2.Text = "Your name is wrong!!"; 
    } 
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text)) 
    {
        Label2.Text = "Please fill in your name"; 
    } 

    if (isname && ismail) 
    {
        {
            Label1.Text = "";
            Label2.Text = "";
            Label3.Text = "Your message has been send!";
        }
    }
}
```